# Too many 404 requests at the same time will result in session lost

Tags: php, apache, laravel, session, http-status-code-404

I have a site which loads a country drop-down with the corresponding flags. I don't have all the flags available at the moment, so I receive a couple of 404's. This is as expected and nothing to worry about.

The strange part is that I lose my logged in session to. When the page has loaded and I navigate away (or even a page refresh), I need to re-login again. This is happening every time, not at random.

If I request only one faulty (404) image in my script, everything works fine, as in that I don't lose my session.

~I'm using Laravel, if that matters

`Ubuntu 16.04
PHP version 7.0.22
Apache 2.0
Laravel 4.2`

Laravel sessions config:

`'driver' => 'file',
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,`

A part of the `apache2/access.log`:

```
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:35 +0200] "GET /admin/user/edit/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 15970 "https://<dev_website>/admin" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Geck$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_0.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12585 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12740 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_4.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12738 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_7.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12583 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_6.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12591 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_14.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12583 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KH$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_12.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12583 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KH$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_11.png HTTP/1.1" 404 12585 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KH$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_21.png HTTP/1.1" 302 1078 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
<IP> - - [31/Aug/2017:14:35:36 +0200] "GET /img/flags/nl_18.png HTTP/1.1" 302 1080 "https://<dev_website>/admin/user/edit/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT$
1
```

Comment: What kind of session driver are you using?

Comment: @GiamPy the file session driver

Comment: It is know to cause issues sometimes, especially for concurrent requests. Try to use a database or Redis driver. I've had them myself in the past, once I changed driver they disappeared immediatly.

Comment: @GiamPy Redis is not running, so I'll setup a database and do some tests with that. This sounds like the solution. Will get back to you when I'm done setting up

Comment: @GiamPy Hmm, seems like setting up the database is failing to me. Probably because it's the end of the day... The .htaccess trick works, so I'll go with that one for now, although I'll keep this in mind for some time later on to look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions that rely on files can struggle to work properly when the browser makes many requests in a short period, because each script execution puts a lock on the session file until the script completes or calls [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php). As a result, the other requests don't have access to the session as soon as they should. That may be contributing to your problem.

I think the simplest solution is to add a RewriteRule in .htaccess that will redirect requests to non-existent flag images to an existing placeholder image.  Something like:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^img/flags/\w+.png$ /img/flags/placeholder.png [L]
```

Of course you need to create `/img/flags/placeholder.png`. The redirect should not affect existing files.

Comment: You could always redirect to http://via.placeholder.com/200x200 (change dimensions to what you need) instead of adding your own placeholder image

Comment: @delboy1978uk cool, I didn't know about that. I wouldn't redirect to it on my own site because it makes me dependent on one more service (new point of failure) and gives that service info about who visits my site. I would generate the needed placeholder image, download it and save it on my own server though.

Comment: I use it so long as my application environment isn't production. Placeholders on all dev stuff, real images on production.

Comment: Somehow the server wasn't that happy with creating a database (everything was going wrong), but this works to. Thank you very much